# How Can I update a JSON file that is hosted in GitHub repository using JavaScript and Github API

Tags: javascript, json, github

How Can I update a JSON file that is hosted in GitHub repository using JavaScript and Github API

Comment: If you want to modify data hosted in GitHub then it sounds like the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) would be the place to start.  Or perhaps a JavaScript Git client, options for which you can find with your favorite search engine.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this wasn't [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where the solution to the actual problem is "Use hosting that lets you run server side code and replace the JSON file with a database".